# ORacle SQL query to find end date from max value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

e.g.
My table contains records as shown below.

```
EmpName       Paycode      ApplyDate            Amt. of Hrs
emp1          vacation      5/1/2010                     8
emp1          vacation      5/2/2010                     8
emp1          vacation      5/3/2010                     8
```

I am trying to get the output like this...

```
Emp Name  Paycode      Leave Start Date    Leave End Date    TotalHrs
emp1      vacation         5/1/2010           5/3/2010           24
```

Can any one help me to fix this.

Thanks
Mart

Comment: Based on your table, it seems possible that an employee has multiple entries for the same paycode eg "emp1 has 2 sets of vacations". Does your application support that possibility?

Comment: If your test data had another entry for the same employee and paycode but with an apply date of 7/5/2010 (e.g. another vacation period), then how should this be reported?  I would think your reporting would only want to group consecutive working days within the same aggregate reporting line.

Comment: @Insame, yes you are correct..

Comment: a single emp can contain multiple sets of records.This is something like if you take one week of vacation in may and another week of vacation in august, if the user wants to see your vacation history for the whole year, obviously all your vacations should come as an output.

Comment: @Dan say another e.g.... if emp2 has vacation period of 7/5/2010 to 7/9/2010, then my output should be emp2 |Vacation | 7/5/2010 | 7/9/2010 | 40

Answer (score 3):

```
select
  empname
  , paycode
  , min(applyDate) as leave_start_date
  , max(applyDate) as leave_end_date
  , sum(amt_of_hrs) as total_hours
from TableEmp
group by empname, paycode
```

Comment: this would 'jump' the gaps in multiple vacations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to have more complex data and only add up consecutive days (as @Dan mentioned in a comment) then you will need a more complicated query.

Something that might solve your problem is shown below. This is a modification of the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277330/grouping-rows-considering-difference-between-rows/4277680#4277680)

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT  'emp1' as empname, 'vacation' as paycode, date '2010-05-01' as applydate, 8 as numhours from dual union all
  SELECT  'emp1' as empname, 'vacation' as paycode, date '2010-05-02' as applydate, 8 as numhours from dual union all
  SELECT  'emp1' as empname, 'vacation' as paycode, date '2010-05-03' as applydate, 8 as numhours from dual union all
  SELECT  'emp2' as empname, 'vacation' as paycode, date '2010-05-01' as applydate, 8 as numhours from dual union all
  SELECT  'emp2' as empname, 'vacation' as paycode, date '2010-05-02' as applydate, 8 as numhours from dual union all
  SELECT  'emp1' as empname, 'vacation' as paycode, date '2010-07-05' as applydate, 8 as numhours from dual 
)
select 
      empname,
      paycode,
      min(applydate) as startdate,
      max(applydate) as startdate,
      sum(numhours) as toalhours
from ( 
  select 
      empname,
      paycode,
      applydate,
      numhours,
/* number the blocks sequentially */
    sum(is_block_start) over (partition by empname, paycode order by applydate) as block_num
  from ( 
    select 
      empname,
      paycode,
      applydate,
      numhours,
/* Mark the start of each block */
      case 
        when applydate = prev_applydate + 1 then 0 else 1 end as is_block_start
    from ( 
      select 
        empname,
        paycode,
        applydate,
        numhours,
        lag(applydate) over (partition by empname, paycode order by applydate) prev_applydate
      from test_data
    )
  )
)
group by empname, paycode, block_num
```

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey...do i require any more blocks of codes in addition to the above code? The above code does not return any rows. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Mahadevan: That should all work without any extra. Returns three rows for me on 10.2.0.4. Are you getting an error or anything?

Comment: @Mahadevan I've just changed to comment format. Might work better. Copying from IE it came out on one line which causes problem. No problems with Firefox though... weird.

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey: Do i need to keep the 'with' clause definition if i want to run it against whole table?

Comment: I modified the above query as below to fit my requirements. but i am not getting any output. what all i get is "SQL statement does not return rows"

Comment: @Madadevan: remove the `with` clause as that is just providing some example data. Replace `test_data` with your table name. Then it might pay to start at the lowest sub-query of the query, see what you get back fro there. Trace the problem. I can't really help debug the query when it is working for me and I'm not getting much info from you apart from saying that it returns no rows.

Comment: @Mahadevan I searched for your error on Google and found this page http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/101721/0/ which refers to the with clause and Oracle 8 client. Maybe that's the issue. Other than that, I can't really help